# Fragment recreates twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I'm trying to restore current fragment in the activity as the app gets killed sometimes in the background. I use `putFragment()` to store the current fragment in `onSaveInstanceState()` and i use `getFragment()` in `onRestoreInstanceState()` to get saved instance of the current fragment before the app got killed, which is done in the hosting Activity.

**onSaveInstanceState() in MainActivity:**

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {

    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "fragment", getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mainfrag));

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
}
```

**onRestoreInstanceState() in MainActivity():**

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    Fragment current = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "fragment");
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (current instanceof SubCat) {
        current = new SubCat();
    }
    ft.replace(R.id.mainfrag, current); //error-line (MainActivity.java:185)
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

I used `SubCat()` fragment to test, it's just one of the fragments of the app, so when the `SubCat()` fragment is in foreground/visible i intentionally put the entire app to the background or lets say i minimise the app, and after some time, when i return to the app, the last fragment( `SubCat()` in this case) is restored back, however i also need to save some instance of the fragment too as well.

Now the problem is that the fragment recreates twice, at first the real value of `cat_id` is retrieved from bundle in `onActivityCreated()`, but some how the fragment is been recreated again, and at this time `onActivityCreated()` is not called which makes the value of `cat_id` null.

**Fragment:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    arr = new ArrayList<>();

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        String[] data = getArguments().getStringArray("cat_data");
        cat_id = data[0];
        cat_name = data[1];
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_category, container, false);

        progress = view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        subCatAdapter = new SubCatAdapter(arr, getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(subCatAdapter);

        subCatAdapter.setOnClickListener(this);

        doThis(); //request data from server
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("cat_id", cat_id);
    outState.putString("cat_name", cat_name);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        cat_id = savedInstanceState.getString("cat_id");
        cat_name = savedInstanceState.getString("cat_name");
    }
}
```

I do not know what i am doing wrong, please help out, thanks in advance.

Comment: please share your error

Comment: there's no error, cat_id returns an empty value..which is not supposed to be, it has a value before app goes to the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured this out by removing the `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` in the MainActivity.
Restoring the `fragment` in the `activity` and also restoring the state of the `fragment` is somehow redundant which makes the `onCreateView()` of `fragment` fires twice. So restoring only the fragment state itself does the work.